# Text is visible on page but not in html as value or any attribute (Angular project). How to get value using selenium or protractor

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```html
<input _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" formcontrolname="email" id="input-email" type="text" ng-reflect-klass="form-control" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="email" placeholder="Email">
```

how to get email input values?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea9Zj.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below option

```
var ele = element(by.id('input-email'));

var inputText = ele.evaluate(ele.getAttribute('value'));  // Returns the text
```

**OR**

```
var inputText = ele.getAttribute('value'); //returns the text
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. can you describe how i will print value in console using selenium c#.

Answer (score 0):

To find the entered value or whatever is there typed in some input use getValue() method

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can bind data from code to template in angular.

1. Template driven forms - [(ngModel)]

**component.ts**

```js
email: string;
```

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" required [(ngModel)]="email" />
```

[Check this for template driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

2. Reactive forms

**Component.ts**

```js
myForm: any;

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
){
    this.ribbonForm = this.formBuilder.group
   ({
      email: ['', Validators.required]
   });
}

OnSubmit(form){
   //any thing you can do with form data
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup] = "myForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(myForm)">
    <input type="email" formControlName="email"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[Check this for reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
const emailValue = await $("input#input-email").getText();
```

or if not inside an `async` function:

```
const emailValue = $("input#input-email").getText().then((text) => text);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the text in html, you can try something like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("input-email"));
var text = element.getAttribute("innertext");
```

Or:

```
element.getAttribute("value");
```